# Color a circle shape over Bitmap

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap

I'm working on application which gets an image and displays it into an image view. when the user tuches the screen I want the image covered by that circle (the circle is positioned were the screen is touched) to remain colored in that area after the screen is touched again.
I was able to draw the circle over the image but when the screen is touched again the image doesn't stay colored.

```
class DrawingView extends SurfaceView {

    private final SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
    private final Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    private Bitmap bitmap1 = null;
    private Bitmap bitmap2 = null;

    private final Point node = new Point();

    public DrawingView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        surfaceHolder = getHolder();
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);
        paint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            if (surfaceHolder.getSurface().isValid()) {
                node.x= (int)event.getX();
                node.y = (int)event.getY();
                Canvas canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
                bitmap1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.nic_eyes);
                canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap1, 0, 0, null);
                canvas.drawCircle(event.getX(), event.getY(), 50, paint);

                bitmap2 = bitmap1.copy(bitmap1.getConfig(),true);
                surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                photo = bitmap2;//photo is used for saving the modified image into galery

            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

}

Any suggestions?

Comment: is there any issue if you use Directly imageView to draw circlr instead of SurfaceView?? It can be done easily by dawing on ImageView directly

Comment: I've try but it doesn't seem to work.
final Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
paint.setColor(Color.RED);
paint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
canvas.drawBitmap(img, 0, 0, null);
canvas.drawCircle(250,250, 50, paint);
canvas.drawCircle(event.getX(), event.getY(), 50, paint);

Comment: you can use a custom imageView for this..and implement touch Event..and within on toucn Event..draw a circle on the image and reset the image to imageView